# Validação de Campos PHP

Tags: php

Galera, é o seguinte, fiz este código e na hora de efetuar a verificação com um usuário que não existe no banco, acaba me retornando a mensagem que o usuário existe e não faz a gravação.

**Neste caso aqui, eu tenho que verificar se já existe algum usuário com nome, cpf ou login já cadastrados no banco.**

Já tentei de outras formas mas também não me forneceu o resultado correto.

```
<?php

include ("conectarbanco.php");

$nome=$_POST["nome"];
$cpf=$_POST["cpf"];
$email=$_POST["email"];
$telefone=$_POST["telefone"];
$login=$_POST["login"];
$senha=$_POST["senha"];

$verifica_banco=mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT *FROM petianos LIMIT 1");

if(mysqli_num_rows($verifica_banco) > 0){

   echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
   alert('Usuário já cadastrado com esse CPF ou Nome ou Login!');
   window.location.href='cadpetiano.html'
   </script>";     


}else{
   mysqli_query($conexao,"INSERT INTO petianos(nome,cpf,email,telefone,login,senha) values ('$nome','$cpf','$email','$telefone','$login','$senha')");
   echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
   alert('Petiano cadastrado com sucesso!');
   window.location.href='cadpetiano.html'
   </script>";   



}

?>
```

Comment: Sua pergunta está formulada de forma bastante vaga. O erro retornardo possivelmente se dá porque o campo CPF no banco de dados está como único. A validação tem como objetivo garantir a consistência dos dados que serão submitados no formulário. É recomendável que estes dados sejam tratados antes do Insert no banco.

Comment: `*FROM` no *select* e por qual razão você verifica se existe na tabela usuários, mas insere na tabela petianos?

Comment: HEEEEEEEEEEEEELP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não está definindo um `WHERE` na primeira query:

```
$verifica_banco=mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT * FROM petianos WHERE cpf='$cpf' LIMIT 1");
```

Assim ele vai verificar se existe o CPF cadastrado ou não.

Comment: Valeu, muito obrigado :D